# Multiple Laravel Apps on nginx webserver

Tags: laravel, nginx, backend

How to properly deploy multiple projects on nginx server?
What do I need:

- dev-app.somedomain.com
- app.somedomain.com

If there is any article about it exatly with the same setup (subdomains) just post me a link, please.

Thanks.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/nginx-setup-for-multiple-projects

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/help-set-up-nginx-subdomain-that-has-laravel